# coral usb example model fails on Ubuntu

Tags: google-coral

I am trying to run the example model on Coral USB accelerator on Ubuntu guest on VirtualBox. I followed the instructions for running the sample model. It all goes well until I run the actual model, where it fails in the following way.

```
VirtualBox:~/coral/pycoral$ python3 examples/classify_image.py --model test_data/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_inat_bird_quant_edgetpu.tflite --labels test_data/inat_bird_labels.txt --input test_data/parrot.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/tflite_runtime/interpreter.py", line 152, in load_delegate
    delegate = Delegate(library, options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/tflite_runtime/interpreter.py", line 111, in __init__
    raise ValueError(capture.message)
ValueError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples/classify_image.py", line 84, in <module>
    main()
  File "examples/classify_image.py", line 61, in main
    interpreter = make_interpreter(*args.model.split('@'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pycoral/utils/edgetpu.py", line 66, in make_interpreter
    delegates = [load_edgetpu_delegate({'device': device} if device else {})]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pycoral/utils/edgetpu.py", line 42, in load_edgetpu_delegate
    return tflite.load_delegate(_EDGETPU_SHARED_LIB, options or {})
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/tflite_runtime/interpreter.py", line 154, in load_delegate
    raise ValueError('Failed to load delegate from {}\n{}'.format(
ValueError: Failed to load delegate from libedgetpu.so.1

VirtualBox:~/coral/pycoral$ dpkg -l |grep libedge
ii  libedgetpu1-std:amd64                      15.0                                amd64        Support library for Edge TPU
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unplug and reinsert the Coral USB adapter. It solved the same issue for me.